# Difference between "and" and "&"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to understand the order of precedence for logical operations and have the following code:

```
declare @T bit ='TRUE'
declare @F bit ='False'

print @T and @F
```

and it returns an error as

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and'.

I replaced 'and' with '&', and the code works again. Why didn't the former code work?
I'm using SQL server.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
print @T & @F
```

Returns `0`

`&` is the [Bitwise AND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms174965.aspx) operator.

> The & bitwise operator performs a bitwise logical AND between the two
>   expressions, taking each corresponding bit for both expressions. The
>   bits in the result are set to 1 if and only if both bits (for the
>   current bit being resolved) in the input expressions have a value of
>   1; otherwise, the bit in the result is set to 0.

In your case `@T & @F` resolves to `1 & 0` and so returns a result of datatype `BIT` with value `0`

When passed to the `PRINT` operator this `bit` result is implicitly cast to string and the result output to the client.

---

```
print @T and @F
```

Has quite a lot wrong with it.

[`AND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188372.aspx)

> Combines two Boolean expressions and returns TRUE when both expressions are TRUE

`bit` is not the same as boolean. They are not interchangeable and SQL Server won't implicitly cast `bit` to a boolean datatype when needed (SQL Server does not implement the SQL Boolean datatype.).

So you would need to use an expression like

```
@T = 'TRUE' AND @F = 'TRUE'
```

instead of

```
@T and @F
```

Even then your problems aren't over - `PRINT` doesn't accept a boolean expression anyway. You could use the expression in `CASE` as below.

```
PRINT CASE 
          WHEN     (@T = 'TRUE' AND @F = 'TRUE') THEN 'True' 
          WHEN NOT (@T = 'TRUE' AND @F = 'TRUE') THEN 'False' 
          ELSE 'Unknown' -- SQL uses three valued logic
      END
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I really learned a lot from that!